# Single code fragment to perform two different operations

Tags: c#, object-oriented, generic-programming

I want to manage music notes in a C# program, and I wrote a couple classes for that. However, I think I'm having trouble respecting the DRY principle. Either this or I'm overthinking things. Sorry if the question has already been treated somewhere else, I couldn't think of more explicit keywords and yet found nothing about my problem.
I couldn't find a simpler example which would fit the explanation of my problem, and I didn't know what to include and what to leave out of my question, so I wrote a quick version and a detailed version of the question.

### Background

Let's say there exist seven **labels** to describe all musical notes (letters from A to G). Of course, there are more than seven notes to any composition, so only seven labels weren't enough. So we started putting them on **shelves** (*octaves*). A note could share the same label as another, but could be on a different shelf (a higher one or a lower one). This is why we find C notes that are higher than other C notes.
Because of all of this, labeling notes is non-trivial in computer representation: there are two separate informations (label and shelf), labels wrap around when a note shifts from a shelf to another, and that has to be managed.

I have the following class which encapsulates both informations about label and octave:

```
public class OctaveNote
{
    // Note is an enum storing my seven labels.
    private Note n;
    private byte o;

    public OctaveNote(Note note, byte octave)
    {
        n = note;
        o = octave;
    }
}
```

I also have these two member functions which are used to pitch a note up or down:

```
public OctaveNote PitchUp(byte tones)
{
    byte octaveShift = (byte)(tones / 7);
    byte newOct = (byte)(o + octaveShift);

    char noteShift = (char)(tones % 7);
    Note newNote = (Note)((((int)(n + noteShift) % 7) + 7) % 7);
    if (newNote < n)
    {
        newOct++;
    }

    return new OctaveNote(newNote, newOct);
}

public OctaveNote PitchDown(byte tones)
{
    byte octaveShift = (byte)(tones / 7);
    byte newOct = (byte)(o - octaveShift);

    byte noteShift = (byte)(tones % 7);
    Note newNote = (Note)((((int)(n - noteShift) % 7) + 7) % 7);
    if (newNote > n)
    {
        newOct--;
    }

    return new OctaveNote(newNote, newOct);
}
```

### The problem

The code is a bit complicated so let's say the logic isn't relevant for now.
The real problem is here: the two methods are **identical**, except for *three* statements:

```
n + noteShift    vs.    n - noteShift
newNote < n      vs.    newNote > n
newOct++         vs.    newOct--
```

I would like to merge the two methods to avoid code duplication. `tones` would not be a `byte` but a `char`, and could take negative values to express pitching downwards, like so:

```
n.Pitch(3)   => n.PitchUp(3)
n.Pitch(-4)  => n.PitchDown(4)
```

The naive answer would be to throw in a few `if` statements here and there to test whether `tones` is negative, and perform operations accordingly, but isn't there a more elegant way? That is, is it possible to write a single fragment code that behaves in a different way when `tones < 0`?

---

The number 7 is being used a lot because (in this case) an octave is comprised of 7 tones. It is used to find the octave shift (integer division) and the note shift (mod).

The only tricky part is the assignment of `newNote`, because `n - noteShift` can be negative and the mod may produce an invalid value to cast back into my enum, so I worked around it by adding 7 before mod-ing again.

For non-musicians out there:

- Notes are represented by letters from A to G and wrap around on both ends: `A` `B` `C` `D` `E` `F` `G` `A` `B` `C`...
- Thus, there can be *different* notes with the same label, for example a C note higher than another C note.
- In order to distinguish these, we have **octaves**. *For example, `C5` is **one octave above** `C4`.*
- Octaves shift upon reaching the C note. This is (partly) because the most well-known scale starts on C, and this is why my `enum` starts on C as well. The following sequence is notes in their natural order: ...`G3` `A3` `B3` `C4` `D4` `E4` `F4` `G4` `A4` `B4` `C5` `D5`...

Comment: How do you represent the note C#? (Pun intended). You should try to reduce your question a lot, focus only on the PitchUp and PitchDown methods. In the end your question might be a better fit on StackOverflow, if so it will be moved. It seems you are doing something very simple in a extremely complicated way.

Comment: Looks like you are hard coding 7 notes per octave. There are 7 white key notes in an octave, but there are 12 total notes in an octave. I think modeling only the white keys will become problematic and not have much usefulness. Seems likely this all being done to handle transposing, and doing that without the entire set of 12 notes per octave is going to cause the transposed melody to shift in modality. For all practical purposes, will not result in a usable transposition.

Comment: @Bent In the full version of my enum, C# is labeled `CS`, as in "C Sharp" ;) And yes, you're right, that question is too long. I'll try to trim it as much as I can, but I tried to prevent such incovenience by writing a quick version and a detailed version. Anyway, I've always had trouble not getting lost into detail when explaining something :( I'll work on it! @ThomasCarlisle Yeah, I voluntarily omitted black keys for the sake of explaining that whole stuff to non-musician people without confusing them more than needed. Don't worry, I do have the full version, with the 5 sharp notes :)

Comment: The opinions of Martin Fowler and Kent Back are that code should read familiar to the domain expert. In OP's case, OP is the domain expert (in musical theory), so as long as the code runs correctly, OP should choose whatever is most familiar. Of course OP should ask other domain experts (in musical theory, and preferably also in musical software development) to review the code and get recommendations. An objection to the code that comes from a pure software programmer (without backgrounds in musical theory) should be relegated to a lower priority.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle: And 12 notes is still not enough, because C Sharp and d flat are two different notes that sound the same (or almost the same; there are keyboards that will actually play them differently).

Comment: @gnasher729 You're right. But let's consider this is going to be used on European standard tempered keyboards. :p

Comment: @qreon: Ok, let's use simplifications that are completely unacceptable to any musician. That reminds me there are notes with double sharp or double flat sign... Quote "In an A# major 7th chord there are four notes. The root, A#; the major third, Cx; the perfect fifth, E#; and the major seventh, which is Gx." x = double sharp.

Comment: @gnasher729 A simple 12-note representation of an octave fits my needs perfectly well, so that's what I'm going to stick to. I'm sorry if you were offended by the fact that I used such simplifications. That being said, assimilating a sharp note and the flat note right above it is what nearly every occidental music instrument does. I know quite some fine musicians around me and none of them seem to consider "unacceptable" the fact that an A# is played the same way a Bb is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like you want something similar to the relationship between a `DateTime` and a `TimeSpan`.  Perhaps you could describe it as a `Note` and a `NoteShift`.  I think that calling it a `Note` instead of an `OctaveNote` is much clearer when you consider that `C7` is a different note than `C4` (C in the 7th octave vs C in the 4th).

Further learning from the relationship between a `DateTime` and a `TimeSpan`, you could reduce the internal complexity of the math by storing the note as an integer.  Whether that integer represents a frequency or a position on the scale is up to you.  The concept of how to represent the `Note` is done in the formatting functions.

Technically speaking there are 12 notes in the modern scale with [A4 being 440Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A440_(pitch_standard)).  Each octave represents a doubling of the frequency so that A5 is 880Hz and A3 is 220Hz.  Those are representative details you can incorporate as a method to get the frequency from the note.

Let's say you have to represent 8 octaves (88 key keyboard starts at A0 and ends at C8).  You could represent all of that as a number between between 0 and 107.  This makes the math much simpler.

```
public class Note
{
    public byte MaxOctave = 8;
    public enum Name { C, Csharp, D, Dsharp, E, F, Fsharp, G, Gsharp, A, Asharp, B };
    private final byte note;

    public Note(Name name, byte octave)
    {
        note = ((octave + 1) * ((byte) name)) - 1;
    }

    private Note(byte newNote)
    {
        if (newNote < 0 || newNote > ((byte)Enum.GetNames(typeof(Name)).Length * MaxOctave))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(newNote));
        }

        note = newNote;
    }

    public Note ChangePitch(NoteShift shift)
    {
        return new Note(note + shift.relativeNote);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var notesPerOctave = (byte)Enum.GetNames(typeof(Name)).Length;
        var nameVal = note % notesPerOctave;
        var octave = note / notesPerOctave;

        var name = (Name)Enum.GetValue(typeof(Name), nameVal);
        return $"{name}{octave}";
    }
}
```

Your `NoteShift` would just have a positive byte or a negative byte for the amount to shift.  You have the math complication in the `ToString()` call, but typically that doesn't get called all the time.

```
public class NoteShift
{
    final byte relativeNote; // package access

    public NoteShift(byte shift)
    {
        relativeNote = shift;
    }

    public static NoteShift AddNotes(byte notes)
    {
        return new NoteShift(notes);
    }

    public static NoteShift AddOctaves(byte octaves)
    {
        return new NoteShift(octaves * (byte)Enum.GetNames(typeof(Note.Name)).Length);
    }
}
```

A further benefit of this arrangement is that you can employ some intelligent operator overloading for addition, subtraction, greater than, less than, and equals.  As well as implementing `IComparable<Note>` and `IEquatable<Note>`.  That can make your library a lot more expressive.  Just make sure the type of operators you overload make sense.  There is no real reason to multiply or divide notes for example.

Comment: I don't know exactly what I was hoping for when I clicked the "Ask question" button, but your solution fits my need so well that I can't see how I didn't think of it before. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Comment: Curious why the downvote?  Obviously the OP said this was exactly what they needed so I did answer the right question.  I'm also pretty well versed in music theory.

Comment: I've been downvoted as well haha. Probably shouldn't pay attention.

Comment: Everyone was, I always want to be open to constructive criticism, it's how we grow.

Comment: I came up with yet another design that is largely inspired by the *absolute representation* you suggested. I think it's even a bit lighter than what you proposed! :) I refactored `Note` to `NoteLabel` and `OctaveNote` to `Note`. You can take a look [here](https://pastebin.com/zKDc13p8). Before you cringe at the public attributes, this kind of stuff is required by Unity in order for the fields to be accessible through the GUI object inspector. That's also why I somehow wanted to stick with part of my original design. That and the fact I'm lazy. :p

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way to do this is to represent an OctiveNote as an integer. This is in swift but it should be easy to translate:

```
enum Note: Int {
    case c, d, e, f, g, a, b
}

struct OctiveNote {
    let rawValue: Int

    init?(rawValue: Int) {
        precondition(rawValue >= 0)
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    init(n: Note, o: Int) {
        precondition(o >= 0)
        rawValue = o * 7 + n.rawValue
    }

    var note: Note {
        return Note(rawValue: rawValue % 7)!
    }

    var octive: Int {
        return rawValue / 7
    }
}
```

With the above, your pitch functions are merely addition and subtraction.

```
extension OctiveNote {
    func pitched(byTones tones: Int) -> OctiveNote {
        precondition(rawValue + tones >= 0)
        return OctiveNote(rawValue: rawValue + tones)!
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
var n = OctiveNote(n: .a, o: 5) // n = A5
n = n.pitched(byTones: 1)       // n = B5
n = n.pitched(byTones: 1)       // n = C6
n = n.pitched(byTones: 1)       // n = D6
n = n.pitched(byTones: -3)      // n = A5
```

Comment: Quite similar to the accepted answer, except it's Swift :(

Comment: Yea, fortunately this is SE not SO. The important thing is the algorithm, not the language it's programmed in. The accepted answer has a better explanation too, which is important. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace PitchUp and PitchDown with a single function. Add a second parameter that tells which direction to change the pitch. For example:

```
public enum PitchDirection
{
    Up,
    Down
}

public OctaveNote ChangePitch(byte tones, PitchDirection direction)
{
    byte octaveShift = (byte)(tones / 7);
    byte newOct = direction == PitchDirection.Up
                    ? (byte)(o + octaveShift)
                    : (byte)(o - octaveShift);

    char noteShift = (char)(tones % 7);
    char temp = direction == PitchDirection.Up
                    ? n + noteShift
                    : n - noteShift;
    Note newNote = (Note)((((int)(temp) % 7) + 7) % 7);
    if (direction == PitchDirection.Up && newNote < n)
    {
        newOct++;
    }
    if (direction == PitchDirection.Down && newNote > n)
    {
        newOct--;
    }

    return new OctaveNote(newNote, newOct);
}
```

I haven't tested this (just whipped it up off the top of my head), but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: or do it with one parameter with a positive shift value meaning to shift up, and negative means to alter pitch down.

Comment: As per @ThomasCarlisle flags are bad.  See fro example https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html

Comment: @MikeHofer if that's the only solution then I'll go with it, but I was looking for something a lot more abstract than throwing in `if` statements and ternaries to branch the correct execution path depending on a parameter's value (be it as a flag, as you suggested, or implied within a parameter's range, as suggested by @ThomasCarlisle) @PeterM thanks for the link, that shines some light on my questioning :)

Comment: @PeterM He argues flags are bad because they obscure the meaning of the call. The use of an enum makes it quite clear in this case - you'll be using "Up" or "Down" rather than "true" or "false"

Comment: @qreon elegant is all fine and good, but you really want maintainable and readable before elegant. Doing this all in one line is no use when a bug is discovered and none of the developers at the company since you left understand what the method is doing.

Comment: @mmathis By elegant I didn't mean something that fits in the fewest possible lines, in that case I'd already have chained ternaries to achieve that. :p By asking the question I was trying to know if there was a well-known, generic and robust design to provide what I needed, and which would possibly avoid `if` statements. As I said, if that were the only solution, I'd have gone with it. Now @BerinLoritsch also suggested a completely different design that fits perfectly well for what I'm trying to achieve :)